# Want to bring div over div bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">    
    <div class="outer-div"></div>    
    <div id="cropContainerMinimal1"></div>      
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer-div {
    padding-top: 75px;    
    padding-right: 72px;    
    padding-left: 69px;    
    padding-bottom: 92px;    
    background-image: url(../images/student-background.png);    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    background-position: center center;    
    height:590px;
}

#cropContainerMinimal1 {
    width:100%;
    height:421px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

CSS is not working for me. If i play with `absolute` it destroys all the structure. How to fix this issue?

Comment: "if i play with absolute"? If you played with relative everything would be fine. Please be more precise. How do you expect us to be of help if your problem description is so vague?

Comment: i want to bring (outer div ) over to (cropContainerMinimal2). I have copied two html structures. both are not working for me.outer div have background png image. i want to bring that over to (cropContainerMinimal2)

Answer (score 1):

Move your `outer-div` inside `#cropContainerMinimal1` and apply following css. You can play with `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties to make it according to your needs.

```css
.outer-div {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

#cropContainerMinimal1 {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 421px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div id="cropContainerMinimal1">
    <div class="outer-div"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```